# Recording name and source path of a file in a persistent storage in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, dictionary, sh

I'm trying to write a backup and restore function for automation.

I'm struggling to populate the dictionary with path information.

Here's a snippet from the backup function.

```
    FILE="path/to/file"
    BASENAME=$(basename $FILE)

    key="$BASENAME"
    value="$FILE"
    test_dict[$key]=$value

    echo ${test_dict[*]}
```

I get this

```
    bash: package.json: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".json")
```

This is my first bash script and I'm not really fussed about what storage type I'm using, be it array, dictionary, etc... all I care about is to keep track of which file belongs where.

This is my first bash script so sorry if this is a trivial question/error on my side.

I'd really appreciate your input on this.

Cheers :)

Edit: test_dict is declared with:

```
    declare -a test_dict
```

Comment: You don't say which line causes the error. Also you don't show how `test_dict` is definied and initialized.

Comment: You need quotes: `test_dict[$key]="$value"`

Comment: `declare -A test_dict` for an associative array.

Comment: @Jetchisel "bash: declare: -A: invalid option", in the example above I used `declare -a test_dict` to declare the dictionary

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have quotes from declaring the strings about the dic. Either way, I tried adding them but I get the same error

Comment: @user1934428 the error is caused here `test_dict[$key]=$value`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is simply that you are actually running a shell that does not support arrays.

Comment: Is the shebang `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell #!/bin/bash

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't really care if its a dictionary or something else if you have any other ideas

Comment: @muriaie: Did you declare the variable as **associative** array (i.e. dictionary)? Otherwise you will get an error if you use it in this way.

Comment: @user1934428 i feel stupid to say that my bash didn't support associative arrays, I updated it and now it all works. Thanks!

Comment: @muriaie : You still had bash 2.x?

Comment: @user1934428 `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got into all of this mess bc my shell won’t accept `declare -A`, which is to declare it as associative.

running `bash --version` spits out:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

all I had to do was to update bash to the latest version. For that I used: `brew update && brew install bash`

Now my code works just fine.

M :)